# How to export animation to DirectX

Tags: animation, export, armature

I have made a character and rigged him, but I need to export the character as x-file. The problem is this won't export correctly. The strange thing is: I tested it with only a simple animation - just rotating his arm - which works.

But if I export the whole animation, the character only moves a bit around.
It looks like the model takes the animation only from one bone, but the armature *is* exported. I can see this in "Open 3D Model Viewer".
I tried to bake the animation, but it did not work. Perhaps i did it wrong - I'm not sure.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and found any solution?

Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ks35u4njoe...ing.blend?dl=0

P.S.: I used Blender 2.72.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by myself. What you need to do is to set the *Rotation mode* of the bones to be *Quaternion*, instead of *Euler*.